# From an evolutionary standpoint, why don’t couples attempt to have as many kids as possible?

Tags: evolution, human-genetics

Many couples have 4 or 5 kids, but it is unusual for a couple to have 10 or 15. Shouldn’t humans have evolved to want as many kids as possible to maximize the chances that their genes are passed down?

Comment: Remember that until 100 years ago even in developed countries, conditions were very different than now -- women often died in or near childbirth, children often died of disease during childhood, hormonal birth control was not available, etc.

Comment: Because many humans are intelligent creatures. and place their personal well-being ahead of abstracts like evolution?  I mean, why on Earth would I give a damn about whether or not my genes are passed on?

Comment: There's strong cultural component to it. It is not uncommon in strongly religious communities to make as many children as possible. Also, baby-boom took place not so long ago, while average number of children in a modern European family is 1-2 (depending on the country).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical family sizes (especially in developed countries) are much smaller than they used to be, because cultural factors influence behaviour (do you want to have 10-15 kids if you can't afford to give them a good education?) From [Kopf and Livni 2017](https://qz.com/1099800/average-size-of-a-us-family-from-1850-to-the-present/):

[image: The number of her own children currently in a 40-year-old woman's household, 1850 - 2015]

More fundamentally, maximizing the number of offspring does not necessarily maximize reproductive fitness, because the amount of resources/care you give to each individual offspring matters; if you have too many offspring, maybe none of them will grow up to be high-quality/reproductively successful. This trade-off affects non-human organisms as well; there is an entire literature in evolutionary biology on optimal reproductive tactics that includes this issue (Pianka 2008).

---

Kopf, Ephrat, and Dan Livni. “The Decline of the Large US Family, in Charts.” Quartz, 2017. https://qz.com/1099800/average-size-of-a-us-family-from-1850-to-the-present/.

Pianka, E. R. “Optimal Reproductive Tactics.” In Encyclopedia of Ecology, edited by Sven Erik Jørgensen and Brian D. Fath, 2567–72. Oxford: Academic Press, 2008. https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-008045405-4.00841-7.

Comment: Wow. Great answer, thanks!